# Running mvn command using IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I want to run a command

```
mvn clean dbmaintain:updateDatabase
```

1. How can I run this command for a project opened in IntelliJ IDEA 12?
2. If I will run this command, will it automatically run the scripts commands on my db server that's mentioned in my pom.xml file or jdbc.properties file?

Answer (score 47):

If your project has been detected by IntelliJ as a Maven project, then you should take a look at the `Maven project` window, on the right side. Your project should show up as a node, with a `Lifecycle` subnode. If you expand it, you will see the available goals, including `clean`.

Right-click on this goal, choose `Create yourProject[clean]` and in the popup window you will be able to add extra goals to run, including `dbmaintain:updateDatabase`. Running this configuration will be exactly the same as running the command from an external command prompt.

If your project has not been detected as a Maven project, try reimporting it by opening the root `pom.xml` using `File > Open`. IntelliJ will ask if you want to reopen the project using the Maven structure.

Comment: After right-clicking on subnode clean, in popup in command: box I typed clean dbmaintain:updateDatabase and then clicked Apply. Then I run it, now when I right-click on that subnode again, It gave me no option of Create yourProject[clean]... is it configured only once? is it ran correctly?

Comment: I don't have this problem. Are you right-clicking on `clean` or on the `Lifecycle` folder?

Comment: NOTE: Your new `clean` option will show up in the Maven window under `Maven | Run Configurations`, and will be something like `YOUR-PROJECT [clean]`

Answer (score 2):

Adding multiple goals in intellij is possible like below

***Step0 :***

Right click maven project in the maven dialog of the windows as described below...

***Step1 :***

[image]

***Step2 :*** 
[image]