# Can I add the button to the part of idea's plugin (maven plugin)?

Tags: plugins, intellij-idea, maven-plugin-development

My goal is to create a plugin that will build maven project with some custom settings. Can i, for example, choose a couple of goal and press my button to build the maven project with my settings?

[image: Сan I add button here?]
.

If it is not possible can i add this action to right mouse button context menu or should i implement my own maven plugin? Maybe there is some other, more beuty way of doing this with actions or somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You need to add a dependency on the Maven plugin and add your action to the Maven.NavigatorActionsToolbar action group.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Maven Run Configuration and run it when you need to execute custom build.

Comment: I know about this solution, but it is not what i'm looking for. Cause a lot of developers will be using it It would be better if I'll create a plugin that will get all config from server. Also It will work with the server, not only building maven goals.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to another post on how to create a run configuration that launches custom Maven goals: [Running mvn command using IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15492461/running-mvn-command-using-intellij-idea/15500344#15500344)

Comment: [I'm sorry but it is not an option for me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15947675/can-i-add-the-button-to-the-part-of-ideas-plugin-maven-plugin#comment22725598_15948140)